# is it possible to have an accordion in html with only one id among multiple siblings

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make an accordion in css and html that functions with one id among multiple elements. Itll be a "copy and paste" type snippet. I'm not sure if it is possible.

ie.

```
<element id="1" />
<element id="1" />
<element id="1" />
<element id="1" />
```

They all need to work independently. Is this possible?

Comment: id should always be unique

Comment: i told that to my boss but he was adamant that it could be done

Comment: Why do you want to use the same `id` for multiple items?

Comment: Its going to be a "template". Something that requires no change from us but works.

Comment: Use name or class to target multiple elements. Never use the same ID on multiple elements.